# how to post the values from chat controller to other tables using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted know, how to post the values from the chat controller to other tables using rails.

```
class Chat < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :visitors
has_many :themes

class Colour < ApplicationRecord
has_many :themes
has_many :chatbots, through: :themes
has_many :user_avatars, through: :themes
validates :hash_code, presence: true

class UserAvatar < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :themes
has_many :chatbots, through: :themes
has_many :colours, through: :themes
validates :image_icon,:presence => true

class Theme < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :chatbot
belongs_to :user_avatar
belongs_to :colour
validates :position, presence: true
```

Here in chat i should able to select colour, position, user avatar and it should be saved in those table, but here I dont know how to post the values from chat controller to other tables (for selecting the colour I am using color-picker)

code for chat_controller is given below

```
class ChatsController < ApplicationController
layout 'dashboard'
before_action :authenticate_user!

def index
    @chatbot = Chatbot.all.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
end

def new
    @chatbot = Chatbot.new
end

def show
    @chatbot = Chatbot.find_by_id(params[:id])

end

def edit
    @chatbot = Chatbot.find_by_id(params[:id])
end


def destroy
    @chatbot = Chatbot.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if @chatbot.destroy
        flash[:success] = "Successfully deleted!"
    else
        flash[:success] = "Deletion Failed!"
    end
end

def create
     @colour = Colour.new(colour_params)
     if @colour.save
        redirect_to chatbots_path
     end
    end

private
  def colour_params
  params.require(:colour).permit(:hash_code)
end
def chatbot_params
    params.require(:chatbot).permit(:id,:name,:description,:embed_id)
end
end



show.html.erb


<%= form_for  @chatbot, :url => {:controller => 'chatbots', :action => 
"create" }, html: { method: :post } do |f| %>
 <%= f.label "Select Theme Color" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :colour_ids %>
     <%= f.text_field :colour, class: "color-picker", id: "theme-picker" %>
    <%= f.submit "Save" , class: "btn btn-primary"%>
<% end %>

# code for position-select


# code for user avatar
```

Comment: In which table you want to post this params and why ?

Comment: user should able to slect the colour, position , and user_avatar and the values should get saved in those tables

Comment: Since you're submitting to your `ChatbotsController`, you should show that code. Also, your form only has a field for `:colour`. Where are the other fields (`position`, and `user_avatar`)?

Comment: are you passing any field like user avatar and position ?

Comment: I have updated show.html.erb